# Django admin search and edit foreign fields

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I've got a two part question regarding Django Admin.

Firstly, I've got a Django model `Classified` that has a foreign key field from another table `Address`. On setting data, I've got no issues with any of the fields and all fields get saved correctly.

However, if I want to edit the foreign field in the entry in `Classified`, it doesn't display the old/existing data in the fields. Instead it shows empty fields in the popup that opens.

How do I get the fields to display the existing data on clicking the `+` so that I can edit the correct information?

Secondly, I'm sure I've seen search fields in Django Admin. Am I mistaken? Is there a way for me to implement search in the admin panel? I have over 2 million records which need to be updated deleted from time to time. It's very cumbersome to manually go through all the pages in the admin and delete or edit those.

Adding Model Code:

`Classified`

```
class Classified(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    contact_person = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory)
```

`Address`

```
class Address(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    build_add = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    street_add = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    area = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.ForeignKey(Cities)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `+` means just that - add a new instance of the related object and relate the object you're editing to that. Because you're adding a new object it will be blank to start. If you want to be able to edit existing related objects from another object's admin you need to use [inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin).

In your app's `admin.py` have something like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from yourapp.models import Address, Classified


class AddressInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Address


class ClassifiedAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [AddressInline,]


admin.site.register(Classified, ClassifiedAdmin)
```

Adding search from there is really easy.

```
...
class ClassifiedAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [AddressInline,]
    search_fields = [
        'field_you_want_to_search',
        'another_field',
        'address__field_on_relation',
    ]
...
```

Note the double underscore in that last one. That means you can search based on values in related objects' fields.

EDIT: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25445572/1280784) is right in that your foreignkey relationship is the wrong way round to do it this way - with the models shown in your question `Classified` would be the inline and `Address` the primary model.

Comment: Doing this gives me a `<class 'appname.models.Address'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'appname.models.Classified'>` error.

Comment: Edit: I think this is because `Address` also has a foreign key. There doesn't seem to be a work around for this, right? I'll post the model code to the original question

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. I have a similar model working perfectly in production. Take out the inlines and see if the search works or throws any illuminating errors.

Comment: Search works fine without errors when the inlines are removed.

Comment: Sorry not sure I can help further. Your model is not only nearly identical to what I have working, it's actually very similar to the one in the django inlines docs!