# class has no foreign key to class

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I've got my Django Models setup as follows:

```
class Cities(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Pincode(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    pin = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.pin


class Address(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    build_add = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    street_add = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    area = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.ForeignKey(Cities)
    pin = models.ForeignKey(Pincode)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.area


class Classified(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    contact_person = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory)
    area_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True,  default='')
    phone_number = models.BigIntegerField(max_length=20, default=0, blank=True)
    secondary_number = models.BigIntegerField(max_length=20, default=0, blank=True)
    more_numbers = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='', blank=True)
    image = S3DirectField(upload_to='s3direct', blank=True)
    secondary_image = S3DirectField(upload_to='s3direct', blank=True, default='')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    location = LocationField(blank=True, max_length=255)
    NO = 'NO'
    YES = 'YES'
    APPROVAL = ((NO, 'no'), (YES, 'yes'))
    active = models.CharField(choices=APPROVAL, default=NO, max_length=3)
    verified = models.CharField(choices=APPROVAL, default=NO, max_length=3)
```

My question is to do with performing inlines as I need data for each entry in `Classified` to be edited in the `Classified` view in the admin itself.

I've tried the following to edit the address in the same view

```
class AddressInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Address


class ClassifiedAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [AddressInline, ]
    search_fields = [
        'name',
    ]


admin.site.register(Classified, ClassifiedAdmin)
```

However, this gives me the following error:

```
<class 'appname.models.Address'> has no ForeignKey to <class'appname.models.Classified'>
```

How do I solve this error? I've looked and tried the solutions from [<class> has no foreign key to <class> in Django when trying to inline models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609556/class-has-no-foreign-key-to-class-in-django-when-trying-to-inline-models) and [Inline in Django admin: has no ForeignKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899523/inline-in-django-admin-has-no-foreignkey) but they don't seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your inline is written the wrong way around perhaps. An inline should be used for dependent model instances. So you can have a `Classified` in an `Address`, but not the other way around, as `Classified` depends on `Address` with a foreign key relation. If you have a foreign key relation, you can just use a regular field instead, and the form will end up with a select box for choosing the address. If you really want one `Classified` object to appear across multiple addresess, then use a `ManyToManyField` instead of a `ForeignKey`, and then Django will generate an intermediate table for you automatically.

Also, you don't need the `AutoField` lines in your code. Django will generate an auto-incrementing primary key with the attribute name 'id' by default.

Comment: But doesn't this defeat the purpose of editing it from the `Classified` view rather than the `Address` view?

Comment: You can change the address for the ```Classified``` with a regular form field. If you want to have multiple addresses for a ```Classified```, you'll need to use ```ManyToManyField``` instead of ```ForeignKey```. You can't create the address for the 'classified' inline, as the the address needs to exist before it, because it's referenced with a foreign key. It's possible that your foreign key relation is backwards, or that you want a many to many.